# How do I cut the line segments in the photo below at a 45 degree angle?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

The red segments are my guides and I want to 'cut away' the line segments on the outside of the red guides. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

With the above situation, ungroup, unlock all. Select all and go to Pathfinder window and hit Divide.

Ungroup the result. Erase the lines outside of clip lines. Erase clip lines.

The result should be just the interior portion of the clip.